# Android GCM automatic receives push notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

With new update document GCM on Android, I have followed this tutorial:  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client. 
It works fine but I sometime I receive an automatic notification with log the bundle data on `onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)`, I got:

> Bundle[{breaking_news_payload_extra=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,
>   collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

My normal push bundle data is:

> Bundle[{message=Message from MyApp, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

What is going on?

Comment: Did you migrate from C2DM or it is clean integration?

Comment: Does the "from" String say that it comes from your own project ID?

Comment: @Koh, good idea. Should I need to check it? Will there be any problem later day if I check the String `from`?

Comment: You could simply log it out if you can reproduce this in your dev environment. This is because I'm guessing a part of your own server code was sending GCM messages when you did not intend it to do so.

Comment: @maohieng I am getting similar payload messages, Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: I am getting the same type of messages, the "break_news_payload_extra" seems to be base64 encoded, so decoding it reveals some more information. So in your case I get this, when trying to base64 decode:

Jeremy Corbyn: National anthem row is 'demeaning tittle tattle' - live ahead ...îhttp://news.google.com/news/url?XXXX

So I guess it could be Google Now notifications leaking or something similar. Having checked into the issue, it doesn't seem feasible to have hijacked the specific token id for the device and your sender id.

If anyone has more information about this, it would be great.

Comment: Did you find any more information about this? We have the same problem in our app.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't figure out the problem but my current solution is check the string `from` if it is equal my google project id. If `from` is not equal the google project id, do nothing.